# React Native, Icon as prop, JSX element type 'Icon' does not have any construct or call signatures

Tags: javascript, typescript, react-native

I am tying to use an svg icon as a prop in my component, but get the error,

> JSX element type 'Icon' does not have any construct or call signatures.

Component:

```
type Props = {
  price: string;
  Icon: JSX.Element;
};

const MapPin = ({ price, Icon }: Props) => (
  <View style={styles.bubbleContainer}>
    <View style={styles.bubbleContent}>
      <Icon />
      <Text style={styles.bubblePrice}>{price}</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.bubbleArrow} />
  </View>
);
```

Parent Component:

```
  import BPIcon from '../../../../assets/images/maps/bp_icon.svg';
    import ShellIcon from '../../../../assets/images/maps/shell_icon.svg';
    import TescoIcon from '../../../../assets/images/maps/tesco_icon.svg';
    import TexacoIcon from '../../../../assets/images/maps/texaco_icon.svg';
    import sampleData from '../../sampleData';

    const MapComponent = () => {
      const renderIcon = (type: string) => {
        switch (type) {
          case 'bp':
            return <BPIcon />;
          case 'shell':
            return <ShellIcon />;
          case 'texaco':
            return <TexacoIcon />;
          case 'tesco':
            return <TescoIcon />;
        }
      };
    
      return (
        <MapView
          ...>
          {sampleData.map((marker, i) => {
            console.log(marker.icon);
            const Icon = renderIcon(marker.icon);
            console.log(Icon);
            return (
              <Marker key={i} coordinate={marker.coordinates}>
                <MapPin price={marker.price} Icon={Icon} />
              </Marker>
            );
          })}
        </MapView>
      );
    };
```

SampleData:

```
const sampleData = [
  {
    name: 'test station',
    icon: 'shell',
    price: '15.00p',
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 52.56504897473243,
      longitude: -1.9835459043698045,
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'test station',
    icon: 'bp',
    price: '10.00p',
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 52.564655445785036,
      longitude: -1.9895132194946084,
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'test station',
    icon: 'texaco',
    price: '12.00p',
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 52.56675992926686,
      longitude: -1.9925531724706291,
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'test station',
    icon: 'tesco',
    price: '12.00p',
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 52.56464922306586,
      longitude: -1.9913983181615922,
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'test station',
    icon: 'texaco',
    price: '12.00p',
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 52.5653679624953,
      longitude: -1.9930410479235137,
    },
  },
  {
    name: 'test station',
    icon: 'shell',
    price: '12.00p',
    coordinates: {
      latitude: 52.563723048919684,
      longitude: -1.9902561905426908,
    },
  },
];
```

Comment: I think you need to use [react-native-svg](https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/svg/) (or something like it) to render svg files

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try to pass the Icon as a function.

```js
type Props = {
  price: string;
  renderIcon: () => JSX.Element; // Update the type of Icon prop
};

const MapPin = ({ price, renderIcon }: Props) => (
  <View style={styles.bubbleContainer}>
    <View style={styles.bubbleContent}>
      {renderIcon()} {/* Call the renderIcon function */}
      <Text style={styles.bubblePrice}>{price}</Text>
    </View>
    <View style={styles.bubbleArrow} />
  </View>
);

const MapComponent = () => {
  const renderIcon = (type: string) => {
    switch (type) {
      case 'bp':
        return () => <BPIcon />; // Wrap the SVG icon component in a function
      case 'shell':
        return () => <ShellIcon />;
      case 'texaco':
        return () => <TexacoIcon />;
      case 'tesco':
        return () => <TescoIcon />;
      default:
        return null;
    }
  };

  return (
    <MapView>
      {sampleData.map((marker, i) => {
        const iconRenderer = renderIcon(marker.icon); // Get the icon renderer function
        return (
          <Marker key={i} coordinate={marker.coordinates}>
            <MapPin price={marker.price} renderIcon={iconRenderer} /> {/* Pass the icon renderer function */}
          </Marker>
        );
      })}
    </MapView>
  );
};
```